# Why do I need reload objects before saving them in order for relations to update?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, mongoid3

Not sure if this a Mongoid specific thing or if applies to the greater active record pattern.
I have the following chunk of code, which works:

```
submission.reload.profile
submission.milestone = self.milestone
submission.profile = @profile
@profile.save && submission.save
```

The relation gets updated correctly. However, if I take out the first line (which I only arrived out through trial and error) it stops working and the relation does not update.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

May be submission have some invalid attributes, when you reload, submission back to validate state and can be saved.
try p submission.errors after save without reload

Comment: That's a good theory. Try using `save!` instead of `save` and see what happens.